# MYSQL - searching for some strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with lots of features, but I used features as just one column.

tbl_shop

```
id     |     name        |    feature
```

I used `php` `implode` to save the data to feature, and it will show like this

```
id     |     name        |    feature
1      |    shop_1       |   wifi,smarttv,cr
```

When I use `LIKE` to search for the data I can actually get the shop properly if I just search for one feature like `wifi`

the thing is if i tried to search for `wifi,smarttv` or `smarttv,cr` there is no problem, but when I tried to search `wifi,cr` that time it would not find the shop, is there any way of searching data like this in `MySQL` ?

Comment: Fix your data model so you have a shop/features table with one row per shop and feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a % in between your shops (or partial shops)

```
select * from table where feature like '%wifi%cr%';
```

Comment: now its working, never knew about this one thank you